# Keeping bash open on a named pipe

Tags: bash, fifo, named-pipe

I'm looking to send commands to a separate tmux pane from vim and I figured the easiest way was to mkfifo a named pipe `/tmp/cmds` and run `bash < /tmp/cmds` to listen for commands to run.

I then do `echo "echo \"hello world\" > /tmp/cmds"` as test, this only works for one command and xargs closes immediately. Is there any way to keep this running after more than one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is no different from running xargs on the interactive shell and terminate with a newline, so it will finish and exit.

you would have to write a loop and execute for each line of input from stdin such as

while :; do xargs < /tmp/cmds; done

not tested so you may need to tweak.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was wondering, here's the script I use for sending commands from vim:

```
#!/bin/sh
FIFO=${1:-"/tmp/cmds"}
mkfifo $FIFO &> /dev/null
while :; do bash < $FIFO && echo "== OK ==" || echo "!! ERR !!"; done
```

Here's a vim function to send commands to this pipe:

```
function! RCmd(cmd)
  :silent! exe '!echo "cd ' . getcwd() . ' && ' . a:cmd . '" > /tmp/cmds'
  :redraw!
endfunction
```

A mapping that sends `make` to the window on `<F4>`

```
map <F4> :call RCmd("make")<CR>
```

Have fun!

Comment: I am trying to do almost similar thing. This method works well. However, I'm wondering if it is possible to do this in a way that keeps the terminal available for interactive use as well? For example: a bash session that works like a normal interactive terminal and also executes commands when something is sent to the fifo.